# How to extract every second row into seperate column in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
col1
aaa
1
bbb
2
ccc
3
```

How do I pull at every second row out of the dataframe and make it, its own column like so:

```
col1    col2
aaa     1
bbb     2
ccc     3
```

I tried this:

```
df[::1]
```

since the second row has an index of 1, but I am not returned the data I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.col1.values.reshape(-1,2),columns=['c1','c2'])
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['aaa','1','bbb','2','ccc','3']
})

df = pd.DataFrame(df.col1.values.reshape(-1,2),columns=['c1','c2'])
df.c2 = df.c2.astype(int) # optional to convert col to int

print(df)
```

Returns

```
    c1  c2
0   aaa 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not as elegant (and as fast!) as reshape I think a readable alternative would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': df.col1[::2].values,
    'col2': df.col1[1::2].astype(int)
})
```

Comment: @RustyShackleford Thank you for taking your time to say thanks :)

Comment: you put in time, and one cant buy back time, the least I could do is say thank you.

Comment: @RustyShackleford True. I also exemplified the accepted answer. Makes it easier to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'][0:][::2]
df['col2'] = df['col1'][1:][::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with `concat`

```
pd.concat([df.col1[::2].reset_index(drop=True), df.col1[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas answers are certainly compact.

If you don't need Pandas, or are just curious how this might be done without Pandas, consider:

```py
import csv
import pprint

# configure the shape of your data
reshaped = [['col1', 'col2']]
row_tmpl = [None, None]

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard input header

    new_row = row_tmpl[:]  # create "empty" row

    for row in reader:
        data_val = row[0]
        
        # index will "move over" as columns are filled
        col_idx = new_row.index(None)
        new_row[col_idx] = data_val

        if None not in new_row:    # all columns are filled
            reshaped.append(new_row)
            new_row = row_tmpl[:]  # make empty for next set


pprint.pprint(reshaped, indent=2, width=20)
```

With **sample.csv** filled with OP's sample data, I get:

```py
[ ['col1', 'col2'],
  ['aaa', '1'],
  ['bbb', '2'],
  ['ccc', '3'],
  ['ddd', '4']]
```

This scheme allows us to change the number of rows to interpret as columns simply by changing the size of `row_tmpl`:

```py
row_tmpl = [None, None, None, None, None]  # or, `[None] * 5`
```

and we should grow reshaped's headers to match:

```py
reshaped = [['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']]
```

Now with **sample.csv**:

```
col1
aaa
AAA
1
uno
foo
bbb
BBB
2
dos
bar
ccc
CCC
3
tres
baz
ddd
DDD
4
cuatro
foobarbaz
```

I get:

```py
[ ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
  ['aaa', 'AAA', '1', 'uno', 'foo'],
  ['bbb', 'BBB', '2', 'dos', 'bar'],
  ['ccc', 'CCC', '3', 'tres', 'baz'],
  ['ddd', 'DDD', '4', 'cuatro', 'foobarbaz']]
```